# Is there reward in watching Islamic videos on the Internet?

Tags: reward

Do we earn reward for watching Islamic videos as we earn reward listening to dhikr, reading Qur'an and doing sunnah?

Comment: One thing, for sure, is that you will earn the knowledge that would guide you to do those good actions. According to [the Hadith](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/4536/is-having-intercourse-with-ones-wife-equivalent-in-reward-to-praying-70-naafil-prayers) which is narrated by *Muslim, 1674*, enjoying what is good is considered a charity that you will be rewarded for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Because you're doing something Good. Like you aren't harming anyone, you aren't doing anything sinful. So whatever you will do which does not cause anyone or yourself any harm, it will give you a reward.